# Storyboard's view controller not showing up when programmatically set as root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, rootviewcontroller

I am trying to change the rootVC based on some condition on the app launch. All of my VCs are made in the storyboard so I am doing it like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
                    // Override point for customization after application launch.

                    checkPhotoLibraryAccess()

                    return true
                }

func checkPhotoLibraryAccess(){

                    if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied ||  PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {
                        showPermissionVC()
                    } else {
                        showContainerVC()
                    }
                }

func showPermissionVC (){

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "askPermissionVC")

                    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = rootVC

                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                }

func showContainerVC (){

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containerVC")

                    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = rootVC

                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                }
```

I have removed the arrow showing the initial VC from the storyboard so that it won't have a conflict with the code. However, I got this error and nothing showed up on screen in simulator:

> [Application] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for
>   UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is
>   not set?

I have now removed the "Main storyboard file base name" property from info.plist. This time the error is gone but still nothing is showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the window programmatically.

Try adding the following to the beginning of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `Appdelegate`

```
self.window = UIWindow()
```

Also in your `showPermissionVC` and `showContainerVC` methods, replace this line:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = rootVC
```

with:

```
window?.rootViewController = rootVC
```